Handsome dude helps a guy who broke up with his wife getting back into dating
I watched the first 15 minutes of this movie on netflix a few weeks ago, and now I can't find it again. 
It started with the main character, an 30-40year old-ish Indian looking guy with a huge nose driving home with his wife, and she says she wants a divorce and that she has been cheating on him.
Then he goes to a club, sits there crying and saying to everyone that "Wife cheated on me with dude" etc. Then a handsome guy who's a boss at picking up chicks comes to him to teach him how to get back into dating. The dude who comes to help him is 25-ish, wears a suit, is classy and handsome. He makes the indian-looking main character get a better style, buys him new clothes and stuff. 
Anyone knows what movie this is? 

Sounds like Crazy, Stupid, Love., except I don't think Steve Carell is a "indian looking guy". - Watch the trailer

@Oliver_C Oh yeah, i was drunk, probably that one. thanks :D

@Oliver_C might want to add that as an answer ;)

The movie you are looking for could be Crazy, Stupid, Love. It stars Steve Carell as the middle aged guy (although he doesn't look very Indian to me) and Ryan Gosling as the uber cool, handsome ladies man.

Almost..... ;-)

@ChristianRau: What, beat you to it?

No, I was refering to the word rotation error. But nevermind.

Oh ya that. I make a lot of those apparently.
